# Generate explicit instantiations with multiple parameters with preprocessor

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, metaprogramming, explicit-instantiation

In my project, I want to have a bunch of explicit instantiations of my templated functions to reduce build time. Now I have a lot of functions, which can have different templates. For this reason (and in case I want to have more of them) I do not want to type them manually, but have them generated by the preprocessor.

An example of what I want to have generated:

```
template bool match_any<x>();
template bool match_any<y<x>>();
template bool match_expr<x,y,z>();
```

whereas `x` is an integer between 1 and a defined `max_dim`, `y` can be one of three values: `real, bool, index` and `z` is either 0 or 1.

I want to generate now any possible combination of those three functions with the parameters (e.g.  `template bool match_any<0>();  template bool match_any<1>();  template bool match_any<2>(); ...`), but not only specifically those, since I have ~100 of those functions with a similar structure.

Through [Using macros to define forward declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74043745/using-macros-to-define-forward-declarations) I have figured out how to do a repetitive pattern:

```
#define REP_INT_1(f) f(1)
#define REP_INT_2(f) REP_INT_1(f) f(2)
#define REP_INT_3(f) REP_INT_2(f) f(3)
#define REP_INT_4(f) REP_INT_3(f) f(4)

#define REP_INT(n,gen) REP_INT_(n,gen)
#define REP_INT_(n,gen) REP_INT_##n(gen)
```

which I can then use like

```
#define GEN(x) template bool match_any<x>();
REP_INT(3, GEN)
#undef GEN
```

Of course it is simple to repeat this pattern e.g. for strings.

But my problem is now, that because of the nature of the pattern (as I pass `GEN` as a 'function') I cannot of two arguments for GEN. Sure, I can altered the repetition pattern so it works also for two arguments, but then I would have to make a new pattern like this for any number of arguments and also for every order of them, which ultimatly kind of defeats the purpose, because I will have a big block for every function - then I can just write it manually.

Does anyone have an idea of to accomplish this with either a different way to 'loop' the possible arguments or how to extend my existing methods so it works for multiple arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add to your macros like so to achieve a somewhat maintainable list:

```
#define GEN_X(f) REP_INT(3, f)
#define GEN_Y(f, x) f(x, real) f(x, bool) f(x, index)
#define GEN_Z(f, x, y) f(x, y, 0) f(x, y, 1)

// GEN_F3 = generate functions with at least 3 arguments
#define GEN_F3(x, y, z) template bool match_any<x, y, z>();
#define GEN_F2(x, y) template bool match_any<y<x>>(); GEN_Z(GEN_F3, x, y)
#define GEN_F1(x) template bool match_any<x>(); GEN_Y(GEN_F2, x)
GEN_X(GEN_F1)
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/785dfa5889d1e931)

We separate our variable generators which we can then chain together to get all our permutations: Your macro generates the `x`'s, which is piped into `GEN_F1`, which handles the single-argument case and pipes those `x` values to the `y`-generator, and so on.

Be careful that although we've made the source code linearly maintainable, we can't avoid the exponential increase to the executable size.

---

To address your extended question, if you wanted to be able to handle any permutation of numbers for two arguments, say for x={1,2,3}, y={1,2,3,4}, intuitively you may want to adjust like so:

```
#define GEN_X(f) REP_INT(3, f)
#define GEN_Y(f, x) REP_INT(4, f)
```

This almost works, but macro expansion prevents using the same REP_INT_* macros again within the one recursive expansion (at least in the way that I've done it).

One work-around is to have two `REP_INT` lists (and at least one of them needs to handle variadic inputs, appending the number to the end). The macros can be identical, except that the names need to differ to allow the expansion to continue.

We can then solve the extended problem like so:

```
#define GEN_X(f) REP1_INT_3(f)
#define GEN_Y(f, x) REP2_INT_4(f, x)

#define GEN_F2(x, y) template bool match_any<x, y>();
#define GEN_F1(x) GEN_Y(GEN_F2, x)
GEN_X(GEN_F1)
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ad685e44d95b927)

Comment: This is very nice and it works for the test cases. I unfortunaly did not include this in my example, but what am I ought to do if two of the arguments are numbers? (e.g. If I want to generate match_any<1,1>, match_any<2,1>, match_any<3,1>, match_any<1,2>.. etc.).

Comment: @wittn, well that's a different question. I'm not sure it's possible without a second `REP_INT` series. I'll have a think about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for thinking about it! Also, by 'a second `REP_INT` series, do you mean a second one in a similar style / length as the first one or would I need one for every combination (because the latter would be extremly long, the first one would be fine though).

Comment: @wittn, no problem. I've just edited my answer to address your comment, but here's an example of how you can have an ***identical*** macro series except for the name: [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a758dc2d33a4ed6)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming C++20 is available to you and you don't mind somewhat complicated macros you could use a recursive macro utilizing the new [`__VA_OPT__` token](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace#Function-like_macros) and [deferred expressions](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms#deferred-expression), which in combination allow (limited) recursion within macros.

<sup>Note: C++20 and `__VA_OPT__` are not strictly required, but they greatly simplify the implementation.</sup>

In your case it would allow you to write something like this:
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/z5ezxrdv4)

```cpp
#define GEN(x, y, z) template bool match_expr<x,y,z>();
FOR_EACH_COMBINATION(
  GEN,
  (1, 2, 3),
  (real, bool, index),
  (0, 1)
)
#undef GEN
```

which would expand to:

```cpp
template bool match_expr<1,real,0>();
template bool match_expr<1,real,1>();
template bool match_expr<1,bool,0>();
template bool match_expr<1,bool,1>();
template bool match_expr<1,index,0>();
template bool match_expr<1,index,1>();
template bool match_expr<2,real,0>();
template bool match_expr<2,real,1>();
template bool match_expr<2,bool,0>();
template bool match_expr<2,bool,1>();
template bool match_expr<2,index,0>();
template bool match_expr<2,index,1>();
template bool match_expr<3,real,0>();
template bool match_expr<3,real,1>();
template bool match_expr<3,bool,0>();
template bool match_expr<3,bool,1>();
template bool match_expr<3,index,0>();
template bool match_expr<3,index,1>();
```

---

### 1. How recursive macros work

[Here's a good read](https://www.scs.stanford.edu/%7Edm/blog/va-opt.html) that explains recursive macros in detail. (or [a shorter version here](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms#recursion))

The basic gist of it is that you can force an expression to take multiple preprocessor scans to be fully evaluated, e.g.:
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ov6E1hqMo)

```cpp
#define FOO(a) [a]
#define DELAY DELAY_IMPL_NOTHING
#define DELAY_IMPL_NOTHING()

// normal function-like macro expansion
FOO(bar) // => [bar]

// function-like macro will not expand, due to delay
FOO DELAY() (bar) // => FOO (bar)
```

while also being able to force an additional scan on any expression by simply passing it to a function-like macro:
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ov6E1hqMo)

```cpp
#define EXPAND(...) __VA_ARGS__

// forcing a rescan on the expression will expand the function-like macro
EXPAND(FOO DELAY() (bar)) // => [bar]
```

Those two things in combination allow us to write a "recursive" macro:
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Yv1vPh5nE)

```cpp
#define RECURSE(fn, value) RECURSE_AGAIN DELAY() () (fn, fn(value))
#define RECURSE_AGAIN() RECURSE

RECURSE(FOO, bar)                         // => RECURSE_AGAIN () (FOO, [bar])
EXPAND(RECURSE(FOO, bar))                 // => RECURSE_AGAIN () (FOO, [[bar]])
EXPAND(EXPAND(RECURSE(FOO, bar)))         // => RECURSE_AGAIN () (FOO, [[[bar]]])
EXPAND(EXPAND(EXPAND(RECURSE(FOO, bar)))) // => RECURSE_AGAIN () (FOO, [[[[bar]]]])
```

Note that expansion of `RECURSE` will not result directly in a recursive invocation of itself. (using `RECURSE` directly within `RECURSE` is impossible because the preprocessor does not allow macro-recursion)

The `RECURSE` macro instead produces a delayed expression, that will only result in another `RECURSE` expansion when another preprocessor scan happens. So the second call to `RECURSE` will happen inside `EXPAND`, after the original `RECURSE` invocation has already been expanded.

But there's currently no way to stop the recursion of `RECURSE` - this is where `__VA_OPT__` comes in to save the day; `__VA_OPT__ ( content )` expands to `content` if `__VA_ARGS__` is non-empty, otherwise it expands to nothing. (which we can use to end recursion once all parameters have been processed)

A simple `FOR_EACH` implementation using recursive macros could look like this:
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/398b79sPr)

```cpp
// forces 3 rescans (2 invocations of EXPAND + 1 for EXPAND2)
#define EXPAND2(...) EXPAND(EXPAND(__VA_ARGS__))

#define FOR_EACH(fn, ...) \
  __VA_OPT__(EXPAND2(FOR_EACH_IMPL(fn, __VA_ARGS__)))

#define FOR_EACH_IMPL(fn, first, ...) \
  fn(first) \
  __VA_OPT__( \
    FOR_EACH_IMPL_AGAIN DELAY() () (fn, __VA_ARGS__) \
  )
#define FOR_EACH_IMPL_AGAIN() FOR_EACH_IMPL

FOR_EACH(FOO, a, b) // => [a] [b]
FOR_EACH(FOO, a, b, c, d) // => [a] [b] [c] [d]
```

`__VA_OPT__` is used within `FOR_EACH_IMPL` to stop the recursion once we have called `fn` for each argument.

The only limiting factor of this approach is the number of additional rescans your macro's provide (e.g. `EXPAND` only provides 1, `EXPAND2` provides 3).

But this can easily be solved by adding a few additional layers of expansion, e.g. this `EXPAND_BIG` macro would already provide 86 rescans:

```cpp
#define EXPAND_BIG(...) EXPAND1(EXPAND1(EXPAND1(EXPAND1(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND1(...) EXPAND2(EXPAND2(EXPAND2(EXPAND2(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND2(...) EXPAND3(EXPAND3(EXPAND3(EXPAND3(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND3(...) __VA_ARGS__
```

Adding another `EXPAND*` macro to `EXPAND_BIG` would result in 342 rescans, so each layer more than quadruples the number of recursive calls you can use.

Note that this does have a cost, namely compile-time. The larger the `EXPAND` macro stack, the longer it'll take to compile, so its best to use the lowest number of rescans that works for your use-case.

So with enough rescans you can basically do anything within macros, like iteration (see `FOR_EACH` above), left folds ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9jfce4xcb); [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70342272/8411406)), or like in your case creating all possible combinations of multiple sets.

---

### 2. `FOR_EACH_COMBINATION` implementation

##### 2.1 The code

First we'll need a few utility-macros (mostly the ones from above + a few additional ones):

```cpp
// Simple concat
// example: CONCAT(foo,bar) => foobar
#define CONCAT(a, b) CONCAT_IMPL(a, b)
#define CONCAT_IMPL(a, b) a##b

// returns the first argument
// example: VAARGS_HEAD(1,2,3) => 1
#define VAARGS_HEAD(head, ...) head
// returns all arguments except the first one
// example: VAARGS_TAIL(1,2,3) => 2,3
#define VAARGS_TAIL(head, ...) __VA_ARGS__

// basic preprocessor if
// examples:
//  - IIF(1)(a,b) => a
//  - IIF(0)(a,b) => b
#define IIF(value) CONCAT(IIF_,value)
#define IIF_1(true_, false_) true_
#define IIF_0(true_, false_) false_

// evaluates to 1 if it has been called with at least 1 argument, 0 otherwise
// examples:
//   - HAS_VAARGS(1,2) => 1
//   - HAS_VAARGS()    => 0
#define HAS_VAARGS(...) VAARGS_HEAD(__VA_OPT__(1,) 0)

// forces the preprocessor to repeatedly scan an expression
// this definition forces a total of 86 scans, but can easily extended
// by adding more EXPAND*() macros (each additional one more than
// quadruples the amount of scans)
// examples:
//   - CONCAT DELAY() (a,b)         => CONCAT (a,b)
//   - EXPAND(CONCAT DELAY() (a,b)) => ab
#define EXPAND(...) EXPAND1(EXPAND1(EXPAND1(EXPAND1(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND1(...) EXPAND2(EXPAND2(EXPAND2(EXPAND2(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND2(...) EXPAND3(EXPAND3(EXPAND3(EXPAND3(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND3(...) __VA_ARGS__

// evaluates to nothing, but requires an additional preprocessor scan.
// this can be used to delay macro evaluations.
// examples:
//   - CONCAT(a,b)                  => ab
//   - CONCAT DELAY() (a,b)         => a DELAY_IMPL_NOTHING () b
//   - EXPAND(CONCAT DELAY() (a,b)) => ab
#define DELAY DELAY_IMPL_NOTHING
#define DELAY_IMPL_NOTHING()

// discards all arguments, evaluates to nothing
#define SWALLOW(...)

// appends an element to a tuple
// examples:
//   - TUPLE_APPEND((a,b), c) => (a,b,c)
//   - TUPLE_APPEND((), a)    => (a)
#define TUPLE_APPEND(tuple, el) (TUPLE_APPEND_IMPL_UNPACK tuple el) 
#define TUPLE_APPEND_IMPL_UNPACK(...) __VA_ARGS__ __VA_OPT__(,)
```

utilizing those macros we can then build the `FOR_EACH_COMBINATION` macro:

```cpp
// if __VA_ARGS__ is empty then it expands to fn(args);
// otherwise it'll expand to FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_RECURSE(fn, args, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(fn, args, ...) \
  IIF(HAS_VAARGS(__VA_ARGS__))( \
    FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_RECURSE, \
    FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_CALL \
  )(fn, args __VA_OPT__(, __VA_ARGS__))

// evaluates the user-provided function-like macro fn with arguments args.
// example: FOR_EACH_IMPL_CALL(foo, (1,2)) => foo(1,2)
#define FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_CALL(fn, args) \
  fn args

// if tuple has at least 1 element it calls FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_RECURSE_APPLY;
// otherwise it stops recursion.
// examples:
//   - FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_RECURSE(fn, (), (a, b))
//     => FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_RECURSE_APPLY(fn, (), (a,b))
//   - FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_RECURSE(fn, (), ())
//     => 
#define FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_RECURSE(fn, args, tuple, ...) \
  IIF(HAS_VAARGS tuple)( \
    FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_RECURSE_APPLY, \
    SWALLOW \
  ) DELAY() ( \
    fn, args, tuple __VA_OPT__(, __VA_ARGS__) \
  )

// calls FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL twice;
// once with the first element of tuple appended to args,
// and a second time with the first element of tuple removed.
// examples:
//   - FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_RECURSE_APPLY(fn, (), (a,b), (c,d))
//     => FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(fn, (a), (c,d))
//        FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(fn, (), (b), (c,d))
#define FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_RECURSE_APPLY(fn, args, tuple, ...) \
    FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL DELAY() ( \
      fn, \
      TUPLE_APPEND(args, VAARGS_HEAD tuple) \
      __VA_OPT__(, __VA_ARGS__) \
    ) \
    \
    FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL DELAY() ( \
      fn, \
      args, \
      (VAARGS_TAIL tuple) \
      __VA_OPT__(, __VA_ARGS__) \
    )

// takes a function-like macro (fn) and an arbitrary amount of tuples.
// the tuples can be of any size (only constrained by the number
// of expansions provided by the EXPAND macro)
// fn will be evaluated for each possible combination from the tuples.
// examples:
//   - FOR_EACH_COMBINATION(foo, (a,b))
//     => foo(a) foo(b)
//   - FOR_EACH_COMBINATION(foo, (a,b), (1,2))
//     => foo(a, 1) foo(a, 2) foo(b, 1) foo(b, 2)
#define FOR_EACH_COMBINATION(fn, ...) \
  EXPAND( \
    FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL( \
      fn, \
      () \
      __VA_OPT__(, __VA_ARGS__) \
    ) \
  )
```

##### 2.2 How it works

`FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL` is the core of this macro.

- `fn` is the user-defined function that will be called for each combination from the passed in tuples
- `args` is a tuple which is used to collect the arguments we need to pass to `fn`
- `__VA_ARGS__` are the tuples from which we still need to pick an element from.

Each call to `FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL` can result in two different cases:

- If there are no more tuples to pick elements from (`__VA_ARGS__` is empty), we just call `fn(args)`

  ```cpp
  FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(fn, (a, 1)) => fn(a, 1)
  ```
- If there are still tuples to pick elements from (at least one `__VA_ARGS__` argument is present) we call `FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_RECURSE`, which checks if the first tuple has any options left to pick from:

  - If there are options left to pick from it'll result in 2 additional calls to `FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL`; one to handle the branch where the first element is picked, and one to handle all the remaining elements:

    ```cpp
    FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(fn, (), (a, b), (1, 2))
    =>
    FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(fn, (a), (1, 2))
    FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(fn, (), (b), (1, 2))
    ```
  - If there are no options left it evaluates to nothing (stops recursion):

    ```cpp
    FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(fn, (), (), (1, 2)) => /* nothing */
    ```

Here's an example expansion to illustrate the expansions happening:

```cpp
FOR_EACH_COMBINATION(foo, (a, b), (1, 2))
=>
FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(foo, (), (a, b), (1, 2))
=>
FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(foo, (a), (1, 2))
FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(foo, (), (b), (1, 2))
=>
FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(foo, (a, 1))
FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(foo, (a), (2))
FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(foo, (b), (1, 2))
FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(foo, (), (), (1, 2)) // expands to nothing
=>
foo(a, 1)
FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(foo, (a, 2))
FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(foo, (a), ()) // expands to nothing
FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(foo, (b, 1))
FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(foo, (b), (2))
=>
foo(a, 1)
foo(a, 2)
foo(b, 1)
FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(foo, (b, 2))
FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(foo, (b), ()) // expands to nothing
=>
foo(a, 1)
foo(a, 2)
foo(b, 1)
foo(b, 2)
```

##### 2.3 Examples

Here are a few examples of `FOR_EACH_COMBINATION`.
Note that you can pass as many tuples as you want and each tuple can contain as many elements as you want (the only constraining factor to size is how many rescans your `EXPAND` macro provides)

###### 2.3.1 Simple loop

```cpp
#define GEN(x) template void do_something<x>();
FOR_EACH_COMBINATION(
    GEN,
    (1,2,3)
)
#undef GEN
```

expands to:

```cpp
template void do_something<1>();
template void do_something<2>();
template void do_something<3>();
```

###### 2.3.2 Your `match_expr` function

```cpp
// helper for getting a tuple of n consecutive int values, starting at 1.
// currently only works up to 5, but can be easily expanded by
// adding more INT_TUPLE_* macros.
// examples:
//   - INT_TUPLE(0) => ()
//   - INT_TUPLE(3) => (1,2,3)
//   - INT_TUPLE(5) => (1,2,3,4,5)
#define INT_TUPLE(size) (CONCAT(INT_TUPLE_, size))
#define INT_TUPLE_0 
#define INT_TUPLE_1 1
#define INT_TUPLE_2 INT_TUPLE_1, 2
#define INT_TUPLE_3 INT_TUPLE_2, 3
#define INT_TUPLE_4 INT_TUPLE_3, 4
#define INT_TUPLE_5 INT_TUPLE_4, 5

#define GEN(x, y, z) template bool match_expr<x,y,z>();
FOR_EACH_COMBINATION(
  GEN,
  INT_TUPLE(3),
  (real, bool, index),
  (0, 1)
)
#undef GEN
```

expands to

```cpp
template bool match_expr<1,real,0>();
template bool match_expr<1,real,1>();
template bool match_expr<1,bool,0>();
template bool match_expr<1,bool,1>();
template bool match_expr<1,index,0>();
template bool match_expr<1,index,1>();
/* ... */
template bool match_expr<3,real,0>();
template bool match_expr<3,real,1>();
template bool match_expr<3,bool,0>();
template bool match_expr<3,bool,1>();
template bool match_expr<3,index,0>();
template bool match_expr<3,index,1>();
```

###### 2.3.3 All 8bit patterns

```cpp
// all possible arrangements of 8 bits, in order.
// all8BitPatterns[1] == {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}
// all8BitPatterns[4] == {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0}
// all8BitPatterns[9] == {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1}
// etc..
#define GEN(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8) {b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8},
int all8BitPatterns[256][8] = { 
    FOR_EACH_COMBINATION(
        GEN,
        (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1),
        (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)
    )
};
#undef GEN
```

expands to

```cpp
int all8BitPatterns[256][8] = {
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1},
  /* ... */
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0},
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0},
  {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
};
```

---

### 3. Try it online!

[Here's a godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/z5ezxrdv4) that contains the `FOR_EACH_COMBINATION` macro & all the examples shown above.

##### 3.1 ... or local

Here's the full code, including all examples from above.

To just see the output from the preprocessor you can use those options:

- For gcc & clang: `-std=c++20 -E`
- For msvc: `/std:c++20 /Zc:preprocessor /P`
  Warning: The msvc-preprocessor is not standard-compliant by default, `/Zc:preprocessor` must be passed to force standard-compliant macro evaluation.

```cpp
// Simple concat
// example: CONCAT(foo,bar) => foobar
#define CONCAT(a, b) CONCAT_IMPL(a, b)
#define CONCAT_IMPL(a, b) a##b

// returns the first argument
// example: VAARGS_HEAD(1,2,3) => 1
#define VAARGS_HEAD(head, ...) head
// returns all arguments except the first one
// example: VAARGS_TAIL(1,2,3) => 2,3
#define VAARGS_TAIL(head, ...) __VA_ARGS__

// basic preprocessor if
// examples:
//  - IIF(1)(a,b) => a
//  - IIF(0)(a,b) => b
#define IIF(value) CONCAT(IIF_,value)
#define IIF_1(true_, false_) true_
#define IIF_0(true_, false_) false_

// evaluates to 1 if it has been called with at least 1 argument, 0 otherwise
// examples:
//   - HAS_VAARGS(1,2) => 1
//   - HAS_VAARGS()    => 0
#define HAS_VAARGS(...) VAARGS_HEAD(__VA_OPT__(1,) 0)

// forces the preprocessor to repeatedly scan an expression
// this definition forces a total of 86 scans, but can easily extended
// by adding more EXPAND*() macros (each additional one more than
// quadruples the amount of scans)
// examples:
//   - CONCAT DELAY() (a,b)         => CONCAT (a,b)
//   - EXPAND(CONCAT DELAY() (a,b)) => ab
#define EXPAND(...) EXPAND1(EXPAND1(EXPAND1(EXPAND1(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND1(...) EXPAND2(EXPAND2(EXPAND2(EXPAND2(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND2(...) EXPAND3(EXPAND3(EXPAND3(EXPAND3(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define EXPAND3(...) __VA_ARGS__

// evaluates to nothing, but requires an additional preprocessor scan.
// this can be used to delay macro evaluations.
// examples:
//   - CONCAT(a,b)                  => ab
//   - CONCAT DELAY() (a,b)         => a DELAY_IMPL_NOTHING () b
//   - EXPAND(CONCAT DELAY() (a,b)) => ab
#define DELAY DELAY_IMPL_NOTHING
#define DELAY_IMPL_NOTHING()

// discards all arguments, evaluates to nothing
#define SWALLOW(...)

// appends an element to a tuple
// examples:
//   - TUPLE_APPEND((a,b), c) => (a,b,c)
//   - TUPLE_APPEND((), a)    => (a)
#define TUPLE_APPEND(tuple, el) (TUPLE_APPEND_IMPL_UNPACK tuple el) 
#define TUPLE_APPEND_IMPL_UNPACK(...) __VA_ARGS__ __VA_OPT__(,)

// if __VA_ARGS__ is empty then it expands to fn(args);
// otherwise it'll expand to FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_RECURSE(fn, args, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(fn, args, ...) \
  IIF(HAS_VAARGS(__VA_ARGS__))( \
    FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_RECURSE, \
    FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_CALL \
  )(fn, args __VA_OPT__(, __VA_ARGS__))

// evaluates the user-provided function-like macro fn with arguments args.
// example: FOR_EACH_IMPL_CALL(foo, (1,2)) => foo(1,2)
#define FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_CALL(fn, args) \
  fn args

// if tuple has at least 1 element it calls FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_RECURSE_APPLY;
// otherwise it stops recursion.
// examples:
//   - FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_RECURSE(fn, (), (a, b))
//     => FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_RECURSE_APPLY(fn, (), (a,b))
//   - FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_RECURSE(fn, (), ())
//     => 
#define FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_RECURSE(fn, args, tuple, ...) \
  IIF(HAS_VAARGS tuple)( \
    FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_RECURSE_APPLY, \
    SWALLOW \
  ) DELAY() ( \
    fn, args, tuple __VA_OPT__(, __VA_ARGS__) \
  )

// calls FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL twice;
// once with the first element of tuple appended to args,
// and a second time with the first element of tuple removed.
// examples:
//   - FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_RECURSE_APPLY(fn, (), (a,b), (c,d))
//     => FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(fn, (a), (c,d))
//        FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL(fn, (), (b), (c,d))
#define FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL_RECURSE_APPLY(fn, args, tuple, ...) \
    FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL DELAY() ( \
      fn, \
      TUPLE_APPEND(args, VAARGS_HEAD tuple) \
      __VA_OPT__(, __VA_ARGS__) \
    ) \
    \
    FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL DELAY() ( \
      fn, \
      args, \
      (VAARGS_TAIL tuple) \
      __VA_OPT__(, __VA_ARGS__) \
    )

// takes a function-like macro (fn) and an arbitrary amount of tuples.
// the tuples can be of any size (only constrained by the number
// of expansions provided by the EXPAND macro)
// fn will be evaluated for each possible combination from the tuples.
// examples:
//   - FOR_EACH_COMBINATION(foo, (a,b))
//     => foo(a) foo(b)
//   - FOR_EACH_COMBINATION(foo, (a,b), (1,2))
//     => foo(a, 1) foo(a, 2) foo(b, 1) foo(b, 2)
#define FOR_EACH_COMBINATION(fn, ...) \
  EXPAND( \
    FOR_EACH_COMBINATION_IMPL( \
      fn, \
      () \
      __VA_OPT__(, __VA_ARGS__) \
    ) \
  )

// helper for getting a tuple of n consecutive int values, starting at 1.
// currently only works up to 5, but can be easily expanded by
// adding more INT_TUPLE_* macros.
// examples:
//   - INT_TUPLE(0) => ()
//   - INT_TUPLE(3) => (1,2,3)
//   - INT_TUPLE(5) => (1,2,3,4,5)
#define INT_TUPLE(size) (CONCAT(INT_TUPLE_, size))
#define INT_TUPLE_0 
#define INT_TUPLE_1 1
#define INT_TUPLE_2 INT_TUPLE_1, 2
#define INT_TUPLE_3 INT_TUPLE_2, 3
#define INT_TUPLE_4 INT_TUPLE_3, 4
#define INT_TUPLE_5 INT_TUPLE_4, 5

// EXAMPLES:

#define GEN(x) template void do_something<x>();
FOR_EACH_COMBINATION(
    GEN,
    (1,2,3)
)
#undef GEN
  
#define GEN(x, y, z) template bool match_expr<x,y,z>();
FOR_EACH_COMBINATION(
  GEN,
  INT_TUPLE(3),
  (real, bool, index),
  (0, 1)
)
#undef GEN

// all possible arrangements of 8 bits, in order.
// all8BitPatterns[1] == {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}
// all8BitPatterns[4] == {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0}
// all8BitPatterns[9] == {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1}
// etc..
#define GEN(b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8) {b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8},
int all8BitPatterns[256][8] = { 
    FOR_EACH_COMBINATION(
        GEN,
        (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1),
        (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1), (0, 1)
    )
};
#undef GEN

int main() {}
```